# AS3: can not make border for label component (mx.controls.Label)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Is there anybody know how to make border for label component (mx.controls.Label)? I read http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html but didn't find the way.

Comment: Label does not support background and border. Use Rect behind Label.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the border color of a [`mx.controls.Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Label.html) component using `mx.core.mx_internal` like this :

```
my_label.mx_internal::getTextField().border = true;
my_label.mx_internal::getTextField().borderColor = 0xff0000;
```

You should know that this method doesn't work with a [`spark.components.Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) component.

Hope that can help.